# magento2 add to cart rest api

Tags: magento2, api, addtocart

i want to know the **magento 2 rest api** for add product to cart
am trying 
**post /rest/V1/guest-cart** and am getting **cart_id** then
**post /rest/V1/:card_id/items** in postman and am getting error like

```
{
    "message": "%fieldName is a required field.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "cartItem"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way only for registered customers:

Request path - http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/V1/carts/3/items

Where 3 is your cart id

Method: POST

BODY:
{
"cartItem" : {
"sku": "24-MB01",
"qty": "1",
"quote_id": 3
             }
}

Cart Id ( quote_id ) you can retrieve via:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/V1/customers/1/carts

Method: POST

The response will be similar to:

"3"

Checked via Postman

Answer (score 0):

here is the swagger documentation of Magento2 Rest endpoints, please search for **quoteGuestCartItemRepositoryV1**, there are some helpful examples, data structure etc.

[swagger doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/)

Thanks.